# C++ getline() doesn't require namespace declaration

Tags: c++, scope

Why is *getline()* from header **string** in local scope and can be used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str;
    getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

That works with gcc. But why? It is defined in header **string**, which should required me to use *std::getline()* instead of *getline()*.

Comment: Side note before you say it's crazy: `operator<<` is defined in `std`. You say `std::cout << "hi";` without explicitly referencing `std::operator<<`. That's probably for the better.

Comment: Thank you! Will read about argument-dependent-lookup!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're experiencing Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL, and also referred to as Koenig Lookup). Since one or more of the arguments is a type defined in the `std` namespace, it searches for the function in the `std` namespace in addition to wherever else it would search. I point you to [Stephan T. Lavavej's video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-1-of-n) to learn more about it and name lookup in general.